# Remove Path From File Name

Tags: delphi, file-io, lazarus

I'm developing a program that needs to parse the file name into a `TTextField`. How to remove the file extension I've already know(or think that I can do like this):

```
var
  FName: String;
  FPath: String;

begin
  FPath := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  FName := ChangeFileExt(FPath, '');
end;
```

But how can I remove the file path from `FName`?

Comment: +1 for figuring out the first half yourself

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add `ExtractFileName(FName);`

Comment: Thank you. I am working on an MP3 Editor, and that is what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at `SysUtils.ExtractFileName`.  I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In newer Delphi versions there is also [TPath.GetFileName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetFileName) from `System.IOUtils`